# Fixing my Python package and module structure so it works with pytest and VS Code

Tags: python

I have this directory structure:

```
memsim/
   __init__.py
   utils.py

   tests/
      __init__.py
      utils_test.py
```

In utils.py:

```
def flatten_free_segments(free_segments):
```

In utils_test.py:

```
from utils import flatten_free_segments
```

Now:

```
$ python -m unittest discover --> finds no tests
$ python -m unittest tests/utils_test.py --> works
```

But in VS Code with Pylance:

[image]

And in VS Code debug:

[image]

#### Question

1. Is my basic directory structure and import statement *valid* and *the right way*?
2. How do I get pylance and the VS Code test runner to accept that?

Comment: What are we supposed to see in the two screenshots?

Comment: The errors. The first one shows that pylance is not finding Thanks! the imported package. And the second one is showing that test in vscode is not finding the tests. But really the most important thing is to verify the way my directories are laid out and my import statements are written.

Comment: Maybe if you click on "Show output to view error logs" in the second screenshot, it reveals if and why your directory structure is wrong?